# OpenGL (ES) -- Drawing a cylinder using triangle strips

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

EDIT SOLUTION: 
 A cylinder in openGL ES:

```
///Storing a cylinder in a VBO
int verticesCyl = 60;
int indicesCyl = verticesCyl + 2;
float cylHeight = .2f;

void initCylinder(GL10 gl) {
        GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
        FloatBuffer vertBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verticesCyl * 3 * 
                4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        ShortBuffer indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indicesCyl *               2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asShortBuffer();

        float vertices[] = new float[verticesCyl * 3];
        short indices[] = new short[indicesCyl];
        for (int j = 0; j < verticesCyl*3 ; j+=3) {
            vertices[j] = (float) (Math.cos(theta));
            vertices[j+1] = (float) (Math.sin(theta));
            vertices[j+2] = j % 2 == 0 ? cylHeight : -cylHeight;
            theta += 2 * Math.PI / (verticesCyl);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < indicesCyl; j++) {
                indices[j] = (short) (j % verticesCyl) ;
        }

        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        vertBuffer.put(vertices);
        indexBuffer.flip();
        vertBuffer.flip();

        int[] buffer = new int[1];

        gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        vertexPointerCyl = buffer[0];
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerCyl);
        gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer.capacity() * 4, vertBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        indexPointerCyl = buffer[0];
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerCyl);
        gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer.capacity() * 2, indexBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

////////////Draw the cylinder
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerCyl);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerCyl);
        gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        gl11.glPushMatrix();
        gl11.glColor4f(shadowColor,shadowColor,shadowColor, alpha);
        gl11.glTranslatef(mainX, mainY, 0);
        gl11.glScalef(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0);
        gl11.glRotatef(rotateCylinder, mainX, mainY, 0);
        gl11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indicesCyl, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        gl11.glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: You're missing a curly brace after the "for" - but I assume that's not true in your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Points to consider:

1. Are you "flushing" the graphics context? (I guess you are using Android, but I don't know the exact API to call)
2. Did you load the buffer with "glBufferData"?
3. Did you enabled the vertex client state with "glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)"?

Comment: Cool... Then, I can assume you have control over other basic "oops", like translation (i.e. it draws out of frustum or behind the near plane or after the far plane), scaling (too small or too big), rotation (since your cylinder does not have the top and bottom circles)... 

In this case, I have two more theories: one, you are using backface culling with wrong normals; two, that (j%2) is an int inside a float array.